# Visual Studio 2010 corrupts user interface

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, designer, corrupt

Apologies if this has been answered before.

I am working on a fairly complex UI in VS2010 (typical Explorer type with treeview, splitters, toolbars etc - using only standard controls), and today encountered a scary event.

An error flashed at the bottom (it was too fast to record it, but said something about _HRESULT and the treeview). The next thing that happened was that about 100 errors popped up, all involving missing controls. I opened the designer view and my UI had reverted to a vanilla user form.

Opening the Designer.vb file revealed that although all controls were still declared, all positioning and instantiation code had gone missing. The file had reduced from 110kb to 11kb.

I was able to restore the UI by copying the missing bits from a backup, however had those backups not been there, or had i just made large changes to it, things would have looked a lot glummer.

Has anyone encountered this before, and if so, is there a way to prevent it from happening again?

Thanks

Boris

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like this happens and it is hard to reproduce. Something similar happened to me a couople of weeks ago where the visual studio layout messed up and it was poping all sort of windows that I had to close everytime I start visual studio.

I guess it just happens randomly without any *good* reasons

Answer (score 0):

I realized this is an old question, but it is the first on Google, so I thought I'd share my solution.

I get this problem a lot, I was able to fix it by going to Tools > Options, and then in Environment > General and **unchecking** the following:

- Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance
- Use hardware graphics acceleration if available

EDIT: oops, I read too quickly. Since this still comes up when Googling "Visual Studio 2010 UI Corruption" I will leave my answer here.